# nested: QueryParsingException[[multi_match] query does not support [fields]];

Tags: php, wordpress, elasticsearch

im new to Elastic press and got some problems on Wordpress multi-network site and got this exception when trying to execute WP-query:

> Caused by: SearchParseException[failed to parse search source [{"from":0,"size":3,"sort":[{"_score":{"order":"desc"}}],"query":{"bool":{"should":[{"multi_match":{"query":"test","type":"phrase","fields":{"0":"post_title","1":"post_content","2":"post_excerpt","3":"author_name","taxonomies":["post_tag","category"]},"boost":4,"fuzziness":0,"operator":"and"}},{"multi_match":{"query":"test","fields":{"0":"post_title","1":"post_content","2":"post_excerpt","3":"author_name","taxonomies":["post_tag","category"]},"boost":2,"fuzziness":0}},{"multi_match":{"fields":{"0":"post_title","1":"post_content","2":"post_excerpt","3":"author_name","taxonomies":["post_tag","category"]},"query":"test","fuzziness":0,"operator":"and"}}]}},"post_filter":{"bool":{"must":[{"terms":{"post_type.raw":["post","page","attachment","events"]}},{"terms":{"post_status":["publish","acf-disabled"]}}]}},"aggs":{"terms":{"filter":{"bool":{"must":[{"terms":{"post_type.raw":["post","page","attachment","events"]}},{"terms":{"post_status":["publish","acf-disabled"]}}]}},"aggs":{"category":{"terms":{"size":10000,"field":"terms.category.slug"}},"post_tag":{"terms":{"size":10000,"field":"terms.post_tag.slug"}},"post_format":{"terms":{"size":10000,"field":"terms.post_format.slug"}},"key_themes":{"terms":{"size":10000,"field":"terms.key_themes.slug"}},"themes":{"terms":{"size":10000,"field":"terms.themes.slug"}},"story_labels":{"terms":{"size":10000,"field":"terms.story_labels.slug"}},"asset-class":{"terms":{"size":10000,"field":"terms.asset-class.slug"}},"region":{"terms":{"size":10000,"field":"terms.region.slug"}},"size":{"terms":{"size":10000,"field":"terms.size.slug"}},"places":{"terms":{"size":10000,"field":"terms.places.slug"}},"organizations":{"terms":{"size":10000,"field":"terms.organizations.slug"}},"people":{"terms":{"size":10000,"field":"terms.people.slug"}}}}}}]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[multi_match] query does not support [fields]];

example of the elastic press code that cause this issue:

```
<?php

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 * Description of ElasticpressFilters
 *
 * @author serafim_inplayer
 */
class ElasticpressFilters
{

public function __construct()
{
    /*
     *  Hook into ep_formatted_args to add wighting arguments.
     */
    add_filter('ep_formatted_args', [$this, 'set_es_search_args'], 300, 2);
}

function set_es_search_args($formatted_args, $args)
{
    $search_fields = [
        'post_title',
        'post_excerpt',
        'post_content'
    ];

    if (isset($args['search_fields'])) {
        $search_fields = $args['search_fields'];
    }

    if (isset($args['exact']) && $args['exact'] == true) {
        $query = [
            'multi_match' => [
                'query' => '',
                'type' => 'phrase',
                'fields' => $search_fields,
                'boost' => apply_filters('ep_match_phrase_boost', 4, $search_fields, $args),
                'operator' => 'and',
                'fuzziness' => 0,
            ]
        ];

        if (!empty($args['s'])) {
            unset($formatted_args['query']);
            $query['multi_match']['query'] = $args['s'];
            $formatted_args['query'] = $query;
        }
    } else {

        $query = [
            'bool' => [
                'should' => [
                    [
                        'multi_match' => [
                            'query' => '',
                            'type' => 'phrase',
                            'fields' => $search_fields,
                            'boost' => apply_filters('ep_match_phrase_boost', 4, $search_fields, $args),
                            'fuzziness' => 0,
                            'operator' => 'and',
                        ]
                    ],
                    [
                        'multi_match' => [
                            'query' => '',
                            'fields' => $search_fields,
                            'boost' => apply_filters('ep_match_boost', 2, $search_fields, $args),
                            'fuzziness' => 0,
                        ]
                    ],
                    [
                        'multi_match' => [
                            'fields' => $search_fields,
                            'query' => '',
                            'fuzziness' => 0,
                            'operator' => 'and',
                        ],
                    ]
                ],
            ],
        ];

        /**
         * We are using ep_integrate instead of ep_match_all. ep_match_all will be
         * supported for legacy code but may be deprecated and removed eventually.
         *
         * @since 1.3
         */
        if (!empty($args['s'])) {
            $query['bool']['should'][2]['multi_match']['query'] = $args['s'];
            $query['bool']['should'][1]['multi_match']['query'] = $args['s'];
            $query['bool']['should'][0]['multi_match']['query'] = $args['s'];
            $formatted_args['query'] = apply_filters('ep_formatted_args_query', $query, $args);
        } else if (!empty($args['ep_match_all']) || !empty($args['ep_integrate'])) {
            $formatted_args['query']['match_all'] = ['boost' => 1];
        }
    }

    /*
     * Exclude posts with defined categories by slugs in array
     */

    if (!empty($args['ep_integrate']) && !empty($args['ep_exclude_categories'])) {
        $formatted_args['post_filter']['bool']['must'][0]
            ['bool']['should'][0]['bool']['must_not'][]
            ['terms']['terms.category.slug'] = $args['ep_exclude_categories'];
    }

    /*
     * If ep_exists_key_themes is true will display all posts with key themes
     */
    if (!empty($args['ep_integrate']) && !empty($args['ep_exists_key_themes'])) {
        $formatted_args['post_filter']['bool']['must'][0]
            ['bool']['should'][1]['bool']['must'][]
            ['exists']['field'] = 'terms.key_themes.term_id';
    }

    return $formatted_args;
}
```

The problem that cause this is when $search_fields got this values (array inside array):

```
$search_fields = array(
            'post_title',
            'post_content',
            'post_excerpt',
            'author_name',
            'taxonomies' => array(
                'post_tag',
                'category',
            )
        );
```

Thanks for Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to flatten your fields :

```
 $search_fields = array(
                'post_title',
                'post_content',
                'post_excerpt',
                'author_name',
                'taxonomies.post_tag',
                'taxonomies.category'
   );
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, will try with that and see what will happen. Cheers